# limit computation $\lim_{x \to -\infty }\frac{3-2x^{4}}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Help me please to understand how to solve this question, why my solution is wrong?:
$$
\lim_{x \to -\infty }\frac{3-2x^{4}}{x+1}=\lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{3-2t^{4}}{1-t}=\lim_{t \to \infty }\frac{\frac{3}{t^{4}}-2}{\frac{1}{t^{4}}-\frac{1}{t^{3}}}=\frac{-2}{0}=-\infty
$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when $t>1$, $t^4>t^3$, so $\dfrac1{t^4}<\dfrac1{t^3}$, and therefore

$$\frac1{t^4}-\frac1{t^3}<0\;.$$

This means that $\dfrac1{t^4}-\dfrac1{t^3}$ approaches $0$ from the **left**, through **negative** values, so that the fraction is positive for large $t$, and the limit is $+\infty$.

I would work the problem a bit differently:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{3-2x^4}{x+1}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\frac3x-2x^3}{1-\frac1x}\;;$$

in the last fraction the denominator clearly approaches $1$, while the numerator tends to $+\infty$, so the whole limit is $+\infty$. (The $x^3$ tends to $-\infty$, but it appears with a factor of $-2$, which changes the sign.)

Answer (score 3):

Precisely we have

$$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\frac{1}{t^{4}}-\frac{1}{t^{3}}=0^-$$
so your limit should be $+\infty$.